# Disk Partition Managment

Tags: centos, hard-drive, partition

my server (Centos with Plesk) is running out of disk space.

Width cfdisk I've noticed there's a partition with free space

[image: image print]

Can I maximize the space in partition sda1 to this free space? if so, how do I do it without any risks? using the option maximize?

Not an expert in server managment.

Comment: Does your disk controller support drives larger than 2TB? If so, why was the partition only made 2TB to begin with?

Comment: Don't really know. This is an Hetzner server and configured with plesk. I have 10x10tb installed and don't really know how they're configured. Hetzner doesn't do support neither